# Why does 'meta_key' return an empty array in get_pages

Tags: get-posts

Very simply, `get_pages()` will return all pages.

I want to get all pages that have a custom field key called 'basePrice', regardless of the value.

But when I try to use

```
get_pages(array(
    'meta_key' => 'basePrice'
))
```

The array is always empty, and no pages are returned.

I know I can create a custom WP query, but I Don't want to, I want to keep this simple, but I also want to be able to output a hierarchical list of children pages nested under the parents when I use a `foreach` loop.

If I use `get_posts`, the meta_key works, but all pages (including children) are sorted into an alphabetical list, not relating to their parents.

Comment: is the `meta_key` the only argument you are passing?

Comment: Yes, it's the only custom arugment I want to pass.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is still true, but i tried this one time and found a similar question:

Understand this is not my answer, but what i found that ended up working.  It was a year ago, and I haven't tried if querying by meta_key works yet...
From this question:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32104826/wordpress-get-pages-meta-key-dont-show-page

This is the answer that was provided:

As of now Wordpress documentation for get_pages() says the function doesn't support querying with a meta_key:

> NOTE: This function will currently not retrieve pages using the 'meta_key' and 'meta_value' parameters in the $args array as described below. Until this is fixed in the WordPress codebase, you may want to use get_posts() instead.

So your code should call get_posts() instead:

```
$pages_args = array(
  'orderby' => 'menu_order',
  'parent' => 0,
  'post_type' => 'page',
  'post_status' => 'publish',
  'meta_key'  => 'dont_show_in_nav',
  'meta_value' => 'true'
);
$pages = get_posts($pages_args);
```

Note that I quoted 'true', since to Wordpress it's just a text field. Also, some arguments for get_posts are slightly different than for get_pages.

Comment: There is no mention of this note on https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_pages/